# Is there any restriction to WindowsInstaller msi database queries in sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, windows-installer

I am trying to run some sql queries on my msi database in c#.But it seems like some specific sql queries are not working.

```
WindowsInstaller.Installer ins = (WindowsInstaller.Installer)new Installer();
string strFileMsi = @"abc.msi";
Database db3 = ins.OpenDatabase(strFileMsi, WindowsInstaller.MsiOpenDatabaseMode.msiOpenDatabaseModeDirect);

string q = "SELECT File FROM File WHERE FileName LIKE '%s%'";
WindowsInstaller.View vw = db3.OpenView(q);
vw.Execute(null);
string q2="SELECT * FROM InstalExecuteSequece ORDER BY Sequence DESC"

WindowsInstaller.View vw2 = db.OpenView(q2);
vw.Execute(null);
```

If i run the same query without **DESC** keyword and all,it works fine.Similarly is the case with **LIKE** KEYWORD also.All of these gives sql exception.

Comment: tried running queries alone ? apart from integrating in MSI

Comment: yes. the simple crud operation works but some keywords like these are not working.

Comment: i dont think there will be any restriction..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Installer implements a subset of SQL described in [SQL Syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372021.aspx). Within that subset there are several limitations, including three that I'll highlight here:

- There is no support for `DESC` or `LIKE`, and `ORDER BY` may not handle strings as you expect
- Update queries cannot modify a value in a primary key column
- There is no way to escape the apostrophe character <kbd>'</kbd> in a SQL query. If you need to match a string value like `'It's'`, you have to use the a question mark <kbd>?</kbd> placeholder in the query and pass a record containing the value to `view.Execute(record)`

Answer (score 0):

To overcome the limited capabilities of installer supported SQL, you can make use of the [`Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller.Linq`](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/DTF/Libraries/WindowsInstaller.Linq) assembly which is shipped with wix. To extract the last sequence number of the InstalExecuteSequece table for example, you'd simply write the following query:

```
var db = session.Database.AsQueryable( );
var lastSequence = db.ExecuteIntegerQuery( "SELECT `Sequence` FROM `InstalExecuteSequece` ORDER BY `Sequence`" ).Last( );
```